# How to use preamble.tex with Rmarkdown rticles template for R Journal Submission

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I have a problem with the `preamble.tex` file used in the Rmarkdown `rticles` template for R Journal Submission. This is the procedure I'm following:

1. Create a new Rmarkdown `rticles` template for submission to the R Journal
2. Knit the document and everything seems to be fine
3. Add some latex code to `preamble.tex` (like `\usepackage{subfig}`)
4. Knit the document and it doesn't compile anymore.

If I just remove `\usepackage{subfig}` from `preamble.tex` then everything works fine. I think the problem is related to the fact that the `\usepackage{...}` code isn't put in the preamble of the .tex document but I don't know how to fix that.

If you want to test I created I git repo [here](https://github.com/agila5/test_rticles_RJournal) with all the Rmarkdown files up to point 3 of the previous list. If I knit the Rmd document that I get an error.

Hope it's clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to [a bug](https://github.com/rstudio/rticles/issues/257) in the **rticles** package, which I just resolved on Github. If you install the Github version, it should work now:

```r
remotes::install_github('rstudio/rticles')
```